# Precalculating additional Java object fields as data warehouses do or doing it on the fly?

Tags: java, object, pojo, calculated-columns, on-the-fly

As I have a data warehouse developer background I try to get my head around whether I should precalculate derived values. I have 1000 numerical one-column data rows. I put them all in a list collection. I have to calculate additional field and sort this collection based on the calculated field accordingly. So would you use DataRowPrecalculated or DataRow as a POJO? It makes sense to precalculate columns in a data warehouse but I am not sure if it makes sense in java objects. The following is sort of pseudo-code but you should get the idea. Using scenario2 I have dirty forEach loop. It seems that scenario1 makes my code a lot easier because DataRowPrecalculated object takes advantage of constructor implicitly calling setter to set precalculated field for every data row.

```
public class DataRowPrecalculated {

private int column1;
private double precalculatedColumn1;

public DataRowPrecalculated(int column1) {
    this.column1 = column1;
    setPrecalculatedColumn1(column1);
}

public int getColumn1() {
    return column1;
}

public void setColumn1(int column1) {
    this.column1 = column1;
}

public double getPrecalculatedColumn1() {
    return precalculatedColumn1;
}

public void setPrecalculatedColumn1(int column1) {
    this.precalculatedColumn1 = Math.sin(column1);
}

}

public class DataRow {

private int column1;

public DataRow(int column1) {
    this.column1 = column1;
}

public int getColumn1() {
    return column1;
}

public void setColumn1(int column1) {
    this.column1 = column1;
}

}

public class Main{


public static void main(String[] args) {
    scenario1();
    scenario2();
}

private static void scenario1(){
    List<DataRowPrecalculated> drp = DAO.getDataRowPrecalculated();
    Collections.sort(drp, new Comparator<DataRowPrecalculated>() {
        //implementation
    });
}

private static void scenario2(){
    List<DataRow> drp = DAO.getDataRow();
    Map<DataRow, Double> map = new HashMap<DataRow, Double>();
    for (DataRow dr : drp) {
        double precalculatedColumnOnTheFly = Math.sin(drp.getColumn1());
        map.put(dr, new Double(precalculatedColumnOnTheFly));
    }
    Collections.sort(map, new Comparator<DataRow>() {
        //implementation
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is it depends.

By going the pre-calculated route, you are doing more work up-front which will slow things down if you have lots of objects. Also, this may be wasted effort if the value is never accessed (for all objects).

By deferring calculation to request time, you could calculate the value once if not already calculated and store the answer for subsequent requests. Unless there's a specific need, my own preference would err towards the second option. If you're application doesn't deal with a significant load, it probably doesn't matter and you can choose the style you're more comfortable with.

As an aside, you may wish to consider if these are immutable data objects and make your setters private.

Comment: Yes, would definitely go for private setters